# Telegram: How to add another(existing) bot to bot_father?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

How can I add another existing bot to my BothFather in telegram?

I have my own bot and I can see it in BotFather and now I am asked to manage another bot (which I have its security key).
But I could not see this bot in my BotFather(obviously, because I did not create it) and I could not find any way to add this second bot into my BotFather in order to change its info or default commands list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a bot that you created yourself with [@BotFather](http://t.me/BotFather) and you can manage its commands, info etc. by talking to BotFather.
Then you have been asked to manage another bot created by someone else and you have been given its token.
Let me tell you that you cannot change the info of the Bot created by someone else. i.e. you don't have the ownership of the Bot.
Bot Ownership transfer is a feature that Telegram Support said will consider in future.

As far as making the bot work, by using the API Token you can go through their [Bot API Documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/).

**[EDIT]**
With [Bot API 5.0](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#november-4-2020), it's now possible to Transfer the bot ownership.

Comment: Thanks! I could not find this changing ownership anywhere and I guessed so but I said lets ask maybe there is a way!
If I do not receive any more answers, I will select it as the correct answer.